# Replace indices with values from a list in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
A | B | C | D | ListVal
---------------------------------
0 | 3 | 2 | 1 | [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3]
---------------------------------
2 | 1 | 0 | 3 | [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]
---------------------------------
2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | [0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45]
```

For each row, I would like to use the numbers in columns A-D as indices to the list in column ListVal, and fill the values in the respective columns. So for the above data frame, I want to convert it to:

```
A   |  B  |  C  |  D  | ListVal
-----------------------------------------
0.0 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.1 | [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3]
-----------------------------------------
0.7 | 0.6 | 0.5 | 0.8 | [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8]
-----------------------------------------
0.35| 0.45| 0.25| 0.15| [0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45]
```

Note that indices per row are non-repeating.

I tried to do this using numpy by converting last column into a matrix and the first four columns to another matrix. But stuck there, as well!

Comment: @beniev nope, just reread it and got it!

Comment: did my answer help you? if yes I will thank you if you will accept it...

Comment: Thanks. I just did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in 2 lines of code:

the dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,2,2],'B':[3,1,3],'C':[2,0,1],'D':[1,3,0],'ListVal':[[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8],[0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45]]})
```

convert it to a list of lists:

```
df_vals=df1.values.tolist()
```

and use the following list comprehension:

```
desired=[[d[4][e] if i<4 else e for i,e in enumerate(d)]for d in df_vals]
```

and convert back to a Dataframe if you want:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(desired, columns=['A','B','C','D','ListVal'])
```

output:

```
print df
      A     B     C     D                   ListVal
0  0.00  0.30  0.20  0.10      [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
1  0.70  0.60  0.50  0.80      [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
2  0.35  0.45  0.25  0.15  [0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking about a numpy solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,2,2],'B':[3,1,3],'C':[2,0,1],'D':[1,3,0],
                  'listVal':[[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8],[0.15,0.25,0.35,0.45]]})

a = df[range(4)].values
b = np.array(list(df["listVal"].values))
c = b[:,a].diagonal(0,0,1).T

newdf = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=df.columns[:-1])
newdf["listVal"] = df["listVal"]
print newdf
```

Mind that this creates a large overhead, since the indexing `b[:,a]` adds another dimension.